# Can only access gvfs-mount in nautilus

Tags: mount, samba, nautilus, fuse, gvfs

I am trying to mount a Windows network drive using `gvfs-mount`,

```
gvfs-mount smb://<server_name>/<share_name>/<folder_name>
```

The folder seems to be mounted correctly, as I can browse it in nautilus. However, I am prompted with `ls: reading directory .: Permission denied` when I try to `ls` the corresponding FUSE mount at:

```
/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=<server_name>,share=<share_name>
```

The folder (`/run/user/...`) is owned by me. I am a member of the `fuse` group. Other relevant information may be:

1. I had permission issues when mounting the same share using `mount.cifs`, but I was assuming that `gvfsd-fuse`/nautilus uses a completely different backend?
2. I only have permissions to access a certain folder (`<folder_name>`) on the share

So how can I make the fuse mount point work?

Comment: The question is also posted over at ask ubuntu, [see here](http://askubuntu.com/q/745756).

Comment: I think the question is more on topic on this forum than on the Ubuntu forum. I would suggest that it remains open here and that it be closed on askubuntu.

Comment: I'd be happy to close the question at askubuntu and reopen this one, if that is possible.

Comment: I don't no why they closed this question it's very relevant

Comment: Is there anyway we can reopen this question?